# Normalize Currency in Stanford NLP not working as expected

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford CoreNLP for extraction. Below is the sentence from which am trying to extract currency along with the currency symbol

**5 March 2015      Kering     Issue of €500,000,000 0.875 per cent**

The data that I need to extract is **€500,000,000 0.875**

NLP by default its giving sentence as

5 March 2015      Kering     Issue of **$**500,000,000 0.875 per cent

So i wrote

```
public static readonly TokenizerFactory TokenizerFactory = PTBTokenizer.factory(new CoreLabelTokenFactory(),
            "normalizeCurrency=false");
DocumentPreprocessor docPre = new DocumentPreprocessor(new java.io.StringReader(textChunk));
docPre.setTokenizerFactory(TokenizerFactory);
```

Now the sentence is coming properly as

5 March 2015      Kering     Issue of €500,000,000 0.875 per cent

But when I do

```
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, cleanxml, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, regexner");
props.setProperty("ner.useSUTime", "0");
_pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
Annotation document = new Annotation(text);
_pipeline.annotate(document);
```

where text = 5 March 2015      Kering     Issue of €500,000,000 0.875 per cent

am getting output as

```
<token id="9">
   <word>$</word>
   <lemma></lemma>
   <CharacterOffsetBegin>48</CharacterOffsetBegin>
   <CharacterOffsetEnd>49</CharacterOffsetEnd>
   <POS>CD</POS>
   <NER>MONEY</NER>
   <NormalizedNER>$5.000000000875E9</NormalizedNER>
</token>
```

So I added the line `props.put("tokenize.options", "normalizeCurrency=false");`
But still the output is same with **$5.000000000875E9**

Can anybody Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When I ran this code it didn't change the currency symbol to "$":

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.examples;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;

import java.util.*;

public class TokenizeOptionsExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Annotation document = new Annotation("5 March 2015 Kering Issue of €500,000,000 0.875 per cent");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit");
    props.setProperty("tokenize.options", "normalizeCurrency=false");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    pipeline.annotate(document);
    for (CoreLabel token : document.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) {
      System.out.println(token);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have added props.setProperty("tokenize.options", "normalizeCurrency=false"); previously however the output is without any currency symbol as <token id="9">
   <word></word>
   <lemma></lemma>
   <CharacterOffsetBegin>48</CharacterOffsetBegin>
   <CharacterOffsetEnd>49</CharacterOffsetEnd>
   <POS>CD</POS>
   <NER>MONEY</NER>
   <NormalizedNER>5.000000000875E9</NormalizedNER>
</token>

Comment: Can u please tell how to write  for (CoreLabel token : document.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) in C#. Because i do not know much about java. and am using c# for extraction.